# Windows 10: Error trying to create a local windows path

Tags: command-line, python, path, administrator, non-admin

I am trying to setup a Python virtual environment by using Python's `virtualenv` package. Because I do not have any Admin. rights I have installed the package using this command:

```
pip install --user virtualenv
```

but when I try to set a V.E. by using this command:

```
virtualenv -p \Python36\python.exe .lpenv
```

it says that virtualenv is not recognized as a command or a an executable or a batch file. So I thought it must be something related to Windows path, that is, for this package is:

```
c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages
```

So I found [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/33681/how-can-i-modify-a-user-s-path-environment-variable-without-logging-out) about how to create a local path without logging in as an admin account.

I used this command to create a local path:

```
C:\users\me>%PATH%;c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\python\python36
```

It does not work. The output is visible in this image:

[Error output after trying to add a path to windows path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HkCl.png)

What is this `C:\Program` error? Is there anyway to solve my problem without admin rights?

Comment: `SET PATH = %PATH%;c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\python\python36`

Comment: @Akina It returned this error: `Set-Variable : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '%PATH%'.`

Comment: Maybe excess spaces? Try `SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\python\python36`.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your time, it returned the error: `The term 'c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\python\python36'
is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` I tried it with other path names like: c:\users and c:\users\me and c:\users\me\appdata not worked.

Comment: @Akina The path that you mentioned above is correct. I have made sure of that.

Comment: Perform it in CMD window, not in PS window.

Comment: @Akina Ohhh at last! It worked! Thanks for your precious help! Can you tell me why doing it in PS does not work?!

Comment: In PS use `$ENV:PATH="$ENV:PATH;c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\python\python36"`. *Can you tell me why doing it in PS does not work?!* Wouldn't it surprise you if a VBA code doesn't work in Delphi?

Comment: @Akina Something else came up! Your solutions worked both for CMD and PS. But when I close and reopen PS or CMD, the path that I defined is gone and so `virtualenv` is not recognized again.

Comment: Of course, it is local change which is lost while restarting cmd/ps window. If you want to do this change permanent you must set new variable value in registry (in system or user environment). To do it you may use `setx` command (in both cmd and ps) - it will be available after shell restart (if you need both set it in current session and make permament then perform both actions).

Comment: @Akina Would you like to summarize your comments and put them as an answer so we may delete our comments and have a real Q & A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update %PATH% in current session**

- in CMD window:

  ```
  SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\python\python36
  ```
- in PS window

  ```
  $ENV:PATH="$ENV:PATH;c:\users\me\appdata\roaming\python\python36"
  ```

---

**Update %PATH% permanently**

Update it in current session. Test carefully that the edition is correct. Then

- in CMD window to set new value for current user:

  ```
  setx PATH "%PATH%"
  ```
- in CMD window to set new value for current station (for all users):

  ```
  setx PATH "%PATH%" -m
  ```
- in PS window to set new value for current user:

  ```
  setx PATH "$ENV:PATH"
  ```
- in PS window to set new value for current station (for all users):

  ```
  setx PATH "$ENV:PATH" -m
  ```

If you set your OS as "Use PowerShell in CMD window" then use PS commands variant in any window.